# Laravel 10 Google Cloud Storage not supported

Tags: google-cloud-storage, laravel-10

After updating to Laravel 10 I am getting this error for Google Cloud Storage. Is there something I can update in the composer file?

> Driver [gcs] is not supported.
> {"view":{"view":"/var/www/html/navihealth_devdigdev_com/resources/views/admin/includes/header.blade.php","data":{"errors":"Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#2000 #bags: []

I tried including "superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage": "^2.2" in conposer.json but got the error.